# If / Elif / Else statement does not work as expected to exit game

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, conditional-statements, conditional-formatting

```
# Reserved for our import statements.
import art
import gameData
import random


# Reserved for functions.
# main_Game() function holds the re-loopable code for our application.
def main_game(user_score, playing_again, option_3):
    user_score = user_score
    # Select 2 celebrities from our data list and display to use.
    random_num_1 = random.randint(1, 50)
    random_num_2 = random.randint(1, 50)
    while random_num_1 == random_num_2:
        random_num_2 = random.randint(1, 50)
    playing_again = playing_again
    if playing_again is True:
        option1 = option_3
        option2 = gameData.data[random_num_2]
    elif playing_again is False:
        option1 = gameData.data[random_num_1]
        option2 = gameData.data[random_num_2]

    option_1_name = list(option1.items())[0][1]
    option_1_followers = list(option1.items())[1][1]
    option_1_description = list(option1.items())[2][1]
    option_1_country = list(option1.items())[3][1]
    option_2_name = list(option2.items())[0][1]
    option_2_followers = list(option2.items())[1][1]
    option_2_description = list(option2.items())[2][1]
    option_2_country = list(option2.items())[3][1]

    # Ask user to guess which is correct.
    print(f"\nCompare A: {option_1_name}, a {option_1_description}, from {option_1_country}.")
    print(art.vs_image)
    print(f"Against B: {option_2_name}, a {option_2_description}, from {option_2_country}.")
    acceptable_input = False
    while acceptable_input is False:
        user_guess = input("\nWho has more followers? Type 'A' or 'B': ")
        user_guess = user_guess.upper()
        if user_guess == "A" or user_guess == "B":
            acceptable_input = True
        else:
            print("You can only enter 'A' or 'B'. Please try again.")
            acceptable_input = False

    # Confirm to user if they were correct and display their current score.
    correct_answer = ""
    if option_1_followers > option_2_followers:
        correct_answer = "A".upper()
    elif option_2_followers > option_1_followers:
        correct_answer = "B".upper()

    if user_guess == correct_answer:
        print("\nWell done you were correct!")
        user_score += 1
        print(f"You're score is now {user_score}")
    elif user_guess != correct_answer:
        print("\nYou got it wrong!")

    while True:
        play_again = input("\nDo you want to play again? (yes or no): ")
        play_again = play_again.lower()
        if play_again == "yes":
            main_game(user_score, playing_again=True, option_3=option2)
        elif play_again == "no":
            return 0
        else:
            print("You have not entered 'yes' or 'no'. Please try again.")


# Reserved for code that runs at beginning of application.

# Introduce user to the game.
print(art.starting_image)
print("Welcome to the higher or lower game!")
print("\nGame Rules: From the 2 options shown you have to pick which celebrity or brand has more Instagram followers.")

# Launch our game by calling the main_game() function. We send through the argument 0 which is the users starting score.
status = main_game(0, False, "")

if status == 0:
    print(art.exit_image)
```

Near the bottom of the code where it asks the player if they want to play again, I am running into an issue. If the user inputs 'no' the first time, it does as expected; exits the game function and prints the goodbye image. If th e user inputs 'yes' it replays the game, which is fine. But, when it runs through the game again and asks the user if they want to play again, and they say no it doesn't work. It just asks you if you want to play again a further time.

It seems connected to the user inputting 'yes'. For example, if the user says 'no' the first time, it works fine, the first time. Yet, if the user says 'yes' then the user has to say no twice for it to exit. If the user says 'yes' twice in a row and plays through the game a few times then the user must input no many times for it to work.

I expect the code to work so that if the user inputs 'no' it will exit the game function. It currently only does so if the user enters 'no' the first time through the game. It doesn't work if you say 'yes' first and then play again before selecting 'no'.

Comment: The "reserved" comments seem to be completely useless, nothing is "reserved" here and the code they seem to document is completely self-explanatory without the comments.

Comment: @tripleee I understand what you are saying. I am only 2 weeks into my Python study so these comments whilst simple are useful whilst I am learning. But I will definitely take your point on using the word reserved which might be confusing as you are right technically nothing is strictly reserved in those spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The game restart is done using a recursive call, but after the call it will just go back to the loop without exiting.

Returning on or after the call should work:

```py
        if play_again == "yes":
            return main_game(user_score, playing_again=True, option_3=option2)
```

Comment: Probably better to refactor it to not use recursion, though. Somehow this seems to be enticing beginners but it's just wasting memory by pushing more stuff onto the stack which is never going to be used for anything.

Comment: Maybe I am with a Schemer's mindset here. In Scheme or (with optimizatrion flags) C++ you can just rely on tail recursion being a free operation spacewise, but Python don't have proper tail recursion.

Comment: Thank you @mcendu this one amendment did fix my code. Also for the other comments I will ofcourse look into more advanced forms of doing this without using recursion once I am abit more advanced with Python. I will take this as a short-term fix whilst I am a beginner.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to split game logic and "wanna play" question. Something like this:

```
def game():
    print('Game logic...')


while True:
    user_input = input("\nDo you want to play? (yes or no): ").lower()
    if user_input == "yes":
        game()
    elif user_input == "no":
        break
    else:
        print("You have not entered 'yes' or 'no'. Please try again.")
```